# How to mangle class names and IDs all throughout ones ERB, JS and CSS in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, uglifyjs, clean-css

How does one mangle class names and IDs all throughout ones ERB, JS and CSS in Rails? Every time I open Facebook or Google in Chrome dev tools I see tons of random class names like `.201g`, `.1ayx`, `c3ag` etc. How do they do that?

I'm already using [Uglifier](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier) for basic JS mangling and [ruby-clean-css](https://github.com/joseph/ruby-clean-css) for CSS minification.

Comment: Have you already run asset precompilation? A lot of of asset processing is skipped as long as you're in the development environment.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think Rails' asset pipeline currently lets you mangle class names and IDs.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?